# Alternative to ReadOnlyMemory to access underlying index

Tags: c#, memory, system.memory

Is there an alternative to `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` that allows access to its index into the underlying storage? (`ReadOnlyMemory<T>._index` is private).

I have a tokenizer that has sliced up a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` source into tokens. Each token also has a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` to represent a slice of the source. This works well, but I have a parser using the tokenizer that needs to create new slices of the original source that cross multiple tokens (e.g. from the start of one token to the end of a later token).

My workaround is for the tokens to reference a `Range` instead of a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>`, but this makes the tokenizer more complex for other clients and makes debugging the tokenizer harder. I'm considering creating my own alternative to `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` for this scenario, but there are several aspects that make it non-trivial.

Comment: Couldn't a token also hold an additional integer property for the original source offset?

Comment: Thanks @GoodNightNerdPride. It felt wrong holding the same information twice, but it might well be a good pragmatic solution

Comment: An very hacky alternative solution might be an extension method on `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` that does an unsafe cast to a structure that exposes the desired property. Similar to [how `Array.Length` has been implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/486142a4b87ed6e3134bd1a8726156fb3f55157a/src/coreclr/nativeaot/Runtime.Base/src/System/Array.cs#L21)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, like you say, very hacky, but very interesting too! I've not seen that before. Thanks for the pointer (no pun intended!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadOnlyMemory<T>` already exposes the internals via the various [`MemoryMarshal.TryGet*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal) APIs. You need to handle 3 different scenarios separately:

- arrays (`TryGetArray`)
- strings (only applies to `<char>`, `TryGetString`)
- custom memory implementations (`TryGetMemoryManager`)

One of those should report `true`, for any valid memory chunk.

However: if these tokens cross different memory chunks, what you *might* want is [`ReadOnlySequence<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.readonlysequence-1), which generalizes *discontiguous* buffers; this is *basically* either a single `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` (or similar), or a linked-list chain where each element holds a `ReadOnlyMemory<T>`. You need to build the chain yourself (in the multiple-segment case), but: that's trivial.

Also note that most code that works with `ReadOnlySequence<T>` should check `IsSingleSegment`, and optimize for the single-span case - since this is so frequent, and is usually much more efficient to work with.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. I've had a couple of previous attempts at using `ReadOnlySequence` but hit problems handling encodings, but `MemoryMarshal` sounds like a way forward.